# How come whenever I make loop cuts, it leaves behind another set of faces?

Tags: modeling

I'm a complete beginner so bear with me.

Whenever I [`Loop Cut`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/loop.html) an object and try to move around some of the vertices, I see that there's another set of faces under my current object.

Before Moving:

[image: Before Moving]

After Moving:

[image: After Moving]

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong or how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: It looks as if you may have duplicate objects there. Please share your Blend file following these instructions: https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I embedded the blend

Comment: You've literally got 2 objects on top of each other there. Just hide/delete one of them.

Comment: Agree with @Psyonic. Roof Support 004 and Roof Support 005 are duplicates in exactly the same place. Select either of them in the top-right outliner and hit  'X' to delete. Then try again.